# SSIS/DATA FLOW TASK for sql command in variable to multiple excel sheets in foreach loop

Tags: sql, ssis, foreach-loop-container

so i have a foreach loop container that is looping over the rows of a table with three columns. In the oledb source I have a sql command with a variable that i build using expression builder. this variable which is a sql query calls those 3 variables in the foreach container. when i preview the sql command i get errors because obviously these 3 variables that it is calling are not known until runtime. moreover, this is causing issues with the excel destination because it says no input columns. please help.

Comment: Do you have any code you could share with us to help see what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried setting default values for the variables?